# best way to generate rows based on other rows in pandas at a big file

Tags: pandas, algorithm, performance, rows

I have a csv with around 8 million of rows, something like that:

```
a b c
0 2 3
```

and I wanted to generate from it new rows based on the second and the third value so I will get:

```
a b c
0 2 3
0 3 3
0 4 3
0 5 3
```

which is basically just itereating through every row(in this example one row), and then creating a new row with a value of b+i, where i is between 0 to the value of c including c itself.
c column is irelevant after the rows have been generated, problem is that it has million of rows, and doing that might generate many rows, so how can I do it efficenly? (loops are too slow for that amount of data).
thanks

Comment: yes, loops by default should be avoided with pandas

Comment: just one constant value of `0` for `a` column? or are there different values for `a`? if there are kindly edit your sample data to show this, and show what the expected output dataframe should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reindex on the repeated index:

```
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['c']+1)]
out['b'] += out.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
print(out)
```

Output (reset index if you want):

```
   a  b  c
0  0  2  3
0  0  3  3
0  0  4  3
0  0  5  3
```

**Note** since you blow your data up by the `c` column and you already have 8 million rows, your new dataframe can be too big on its own.